# Jenkins pipeline parallel scheduling

Tags: jenkins, groovy, parallel-processing, jenkins-pipeline

I thought this code should work

```
stage ('test') {
def branches = [:]
def test_jobs = [:]
def  jobnames = ["HW_run1", "HW_run2", "HW_run3", "HW_run4"]

node ('master') {
    jobnames.each { jobname -> 
       branches [jobname] = { jj=build job: jobname;
       test_jobs[jobname] = jj.getDuration()
       }
    }

    try {
         parallel branches
    } catch (e) {
        println "Unit test stage failed with error " + e
    }
}
}
```

But it doesn't, only the fourth job is scheduled:

```
[Pipeline] parallel
[Pipeline] [HW_run1] { (Branch: HW_run1)
[Pipeline] [HW_run2] { (Branch: HW_run2)
[Pipeline] [HW_run3] { (Branch: HW_run3)
[Pipeline] [HW_run4] { (Branch: HW_run4)
[Pipeline] [HW_run1] build (Building HW_run4)
[HW_run1] Scheduling project: HW_run4
[Pipeline] [HW_run2] build (Building HW_run4)
[HW_run2] Scheduling project: HW_run4
[Pipeline] [HW_run3] build (Building HW_run4)
[HW_run3] Scheduling project: HW_run4
[Pipeline] [HW_run4] build (Building HW_run4)
[HW_run4] Scheduling project: HW_run4
[HW_run1] Starting building: HW_run4 #3
[HW_run2] Starting building: HW_run4 #3
[HW_run3] Starting building: HW_run4 #3
[HW_run4] Starting building: HW_run4 #3

[Pipeline] [HW_run1] }
[Pipeline] [HW_run2] }
[Pipeline] [HW_run3] }
[Pipeline] [HW_run4] }
[Pipeline] // parallel
```

I am using Pipeline version 2.5 and Jenkins 2.46.3.

Am I doing something unsupported? Or do I have the groovy syntax wrong? The issue is related to the list of jobs, if I don't use a list everything works just fine.

Comment: Oh well. I fixed it by updating the Pipeline Groovy plugin from 2.34 to 2.41 (this also updated Script Security, Pipeline Step API, Pipeline API) so I suppose there was an issue in one of those.

Comment: Actually that was not the problem - I now have one job working properly and one not working on the same server. Confused.